# How to calculate number of views in my viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview

Currently i am generating "n" number of custom views in my DeatilViewController screen.So i want to calculate the number of views present in my `DeatilViewController.xib` and they belongs to which class.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `NSArray *subViews = [DeatilViewController.view subviews];` or for their count

`NSInteger count = [[DeatilViewController.view subviews] count];`

Answer (score 0):

`UIViewController` has a property called `view` that returns the controller's view. This `UIView` in turns has a property `subviews` that returns the subviews of the view.
Get the length of this array and you got your subviews.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIView